# Prevent extra space being inserted into a CHAR field?

Tags: ms-access, create-table

I create a table in MS Access using the following script:

```
CREATE TABLE POWERSQL (
 ProposalNumber  INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY,
 FirstName   CHAR (15),
 LastName   CHAR (20),
 Address    CHAR (30),
 City    CHAR (25),
 StateProvince  CHAR (2),
 PostalCode   CHAR (10),
 Country    CHAR (30),
 Phone    CHAR (14),
 HowKnown   CHAR (30),
Proposal   CHAR (50),
BusinessOrCharity CHAR (1) );
```

When insert some value to a CHAR filed which is shorter than the set length, e.g., 'John' in [FirstName], it fills the remaining characters with empty space which messes up with other queries and joins. Trim does not help. Any advice? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`CHAR` fields are half-supported in MS Access and are fixed-length. This means you can't insert less characters than the full field length, and if you do, Access will fill the unused positions with spaces.

Instead, use `VARCHAR` for variable-length character fields:

```
CREATE TABLE POWERSQL (
 ProposalNumber  INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY,
 FirstName   VARCHAR (15),
 etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the fixed length `CHAR(x)` data type, use `TEXT`, like:

```
FirstName   TEXT,
.................
```

The `TEXT` data type is variable length and can store up to 255 characters

Comment: I generally recommend against using the `TEXT` data type, according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/equivalent-ansi-sql-data-types) it can mean both a _Long Text_ field to have compatibility with SQL server (probably only in SQL Server compatibility mode), a _CHAR_ field if there's a field length specified, and apparently a _Short Text_ field too.

Comment: @ErikA When a column is created with the TEXT Data Type MS Access **always** creates a column with a Max Length = 255. You can try it.

Comment: @ErikA the link to the docs that you posted refer to compatibility and not to the data type of the column created.

Comment: I have. You're wrong. `CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "CREATE TABLE T1(F1 TEXT)"` creates a table with a field with the _Long Text_ data type. Same goes when SQL Server Compatible Syntax is enabled. That query has context dependent behavior, which should generally be avoided when possible.

Comment: You are wrong. `CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "CREATE TABLE T1(F1 TEXT)"` creates a column of data type TEXT with max length = 255.

Comment: Have you actually ran that? Try it, you're wrong (at least on build 10730, but AFAIK this behaviour is consistent since at least Office 2007 between all builds), I can provide screenshots if you wish

Comment: Of course I tried it and got the results I mentioned in `Microsoft Access 2010 (14.0.7237.5000)`

Comment: Well... I have too, which is exactly why I dislike the _TEXT_ field type and recommend not using it (small [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sURrA.png)). It's even worse than I thought if this behaviour is inconsistent between recent Office versions

Comment: Check this: [![screenshot][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEMnh.png

Comment: I do believe that works for your system, just not for mine, which is exactly why I truly dislike `TEXT`. As for _always_, that can be disputed by N=1 and it doesn't for me.

Comment: If it is N=1 then how do you explain this: https://sourcedaddy.com/ms-access/sql-data-types.html Read the part: *The TEXT data type is a variable-length data type that stores a combination of text and numbers up to 255 characters* near the end of the page.

Comment: As said, the behavior is context-dependent. Obviously, the author of that document was unaware of that and thus propagates the misbelief that it's consistent. And I tend to trust the official docs over some random internet manual.

Comment: The problem is that you misread the docs and disregard the facts. The link of the docs you posted do not mention anything about your claims.

Comment: FWIW, I'm also on Microsoft Access 2010 (14.0.7237.5000) (32-bit), and the above creates a `Memo` field for me.

Comment: Fine, so let the OP try it, but don't say that something that happens only at your system would happen everywhere.

Comment: @forpas My exact problem is that you state it's for every system. I've only said it's context dependent (varies per system) which is exactly why I recommend not using it (it might work for OP, then suddenly cause bugs years later, which is worse than it not working imo).

Comment: ... while `CurrentDb.Execute "CREATE TABLE T1(F1 TEXT)"` creates a `Text(255)` field. Yikes.

Comment: Do you think that I write code only on 1 pc? I have never seen the behavior you mention neither in code nor in any document.

Comment: @Andre meaning?

Comment: Meaning, executing the command via ADO yields Memo, via DAO yields Text. Meaning, I'm with Erik here, `VARCHAR` seems like the better choice for being disambiguous.

Comment: Many thanks all for the advice. I replaced Char by Varchar and my problem got resolved. Much appreciated.